# How to nest Stack Navigation into Tab Navigation in Expo Router V2?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-router

when I start the app my navigation tab appears at the bottom. A stack navigation should appear on one of the screens linked there (settings page). However, the tab navigation should be retained. How can I achieve this? Here is a very simple graphic of how it should be structured

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZnya.png)

I have already looked at the documentation and further information.

Comment: Add  StackNavigator as component of the TabNavigator like this example: `<Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountNavigator} />`